# Angular2 - Calculate discount formula not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing a very stupid problem with Angular2/Typescript.

I want to calculate the final price from a given discount value. This is the formula:

```
row.priceList = row.pricePurchase + (row.pricePurchase * row.markUp / 100);
```

All the properties are defined as number.

If I try to run the formula and log the values, providing pricePurchase value as 1 and markUp value as 0, the result of the formula is 10 ?

How is it possible and how can I correct it ?

Thanks to support

Comment: Sure you are not doing something like `1 + '0'` ?

Comment: yeah, thats it bugs

Comment: I fixed it by changing the formula in: +row.pricePurchase + ((+row.pricePurchase * +row.markUp) / 100);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the formula in:

```
+row.pricePurchase + ((+row.pricePurchase * +row.markUp) / 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try by using `Number` as below

```
const purchase = Number(row.pricePurchase);
row.priceList =  purchase + (purchase * Number(row.markUp) / 100);
```

Other way is already added by you which making use of `+`

```
const purchase = +row.pricePurchase;
row.priceList =  purchase + (purchase * +row.markUp / 100);
```